# Play/stop UIButton toggle using selected property for state not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uibutton, state

I can't see what the problem is with my code. Nothing happens when I press the button, like as if the default state wasn't even set, which is weird because we can't do something `playButton.state = UIControlStateNormal` since the `state` property is read-only.

This is my code:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {

    // ...

    playButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    playButton.frame = CGRectMake(100, 500, 100, 50);
    [playButton setTitle:@"play" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
    [playButton setTitle:@"stop" forState: UIControlStateSelected];
    playButton.exclusiveTouch = YES;
    playButton.selected = NO;
    [playButton addTarget:self action:@selector(play) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

and

```
- (void) play {

    if (playButton.state == UIControlStateNormal) {

        playButton.selected = YES;

        CABasicAnimation *maskAnim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position.x"];
        maskAnim.byValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:diagramWidth];
        maskAnim.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;
        maskAnim.duration = 1.750f;
        [self.maskLayer addAnimation:maskAnim forKey:@"position.x"];
        self.diagramLayer.mask = maskLayer;

        [backImageLayer addSublayer: self.diagramLayer];


        [audioPlayerNormal play];
        [moviePlayerNormal play]; 


    }
        else if (playButton.state == UIControlStateSelected) {

            playButton.selected = NO;

            [self.maskLayer removeAnimationForKey:@"position.x"];
            self.diagramLayer.mask = nil;

            [audioPlayerNormal stop];
            [moviePlayerNormal stop];

        }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code should do the job.

```
- (void) play {

    if (playButton.selected == NO) {

        CABasicAnimation *maskAnim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position.x"];
        maskAnim.byValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:diagramWidth];
        maskAnim.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;
        maskAnim.duration = 1.750f;
        [self.maskLayer addAnimation:maskAnim forKey:@"position.x"];
        self.diagramLayer.mask = maskLayer;

        [backImageLayer addSublayer: self.diagramLayer];


        [audioPlayerNormal play];
        [moviePlayerNormal play]; 


    }
    else {
        [self.maskLayer removeAnimationForKey:@"position.x"];
        self.diagramLayer.mask = nil;

        [audioPlayerNormal stop];
        [moviePlayerNormal stop];

    }
    playButton.selected = !playButton.selected;
}
```

Comment: Indeed it does! Thank you very much. But there something I didn't understand: what's the problem of checking the state of the control inside an if-statement, like I was doing?

Comment: Even i wasnt knowing. Tried to NSLog the button state in its action method. And it says the button was in highlighted state. I guess it remains in highlighted state until it returns from the action method.

Comment: Checked the same thing. Kinda of makes sense that it stays highlighted while it runs the action method, though, in case you want to show something while your finger is still pressed. Anyway, thanks again for the help. Cheers.